# When is a paper finished?

Tags: soft-question, mathematical-philosophy, research

How much truth is there to Chomsky's remark that "mathematicians stop working when things get too difficult"?

https://youtu.be/atupfHizJxM?t=453

Is this true in your own work? How do you know you are finished with a given line of inquiry (at least for the time being) and it's time to publish the paper?

Is stating open questions at the end of a paper an admission of defeat?  Is there any rule of thumb you use on deciding whether or not to post/publish your questions?

Comment: I like my papers to have a clear *purpose* (usually formalised as a "Main Theorem").

At the beginning, there's usually a bit of background (e.g. recalling definitions and known results). And at the end I collect some afterthoughts (e.g. listing related open questions).

If the main theorem reads cleanly, then I'm happy with the paper. If, on the other hand, the main theorem is likely to ...

Comment: ...not be sharp, or if it's not phrased in its appropriate level of generality, then I would say that there's room for improvement. In those cases, I tend to try to work a bit harder on the paper (and encourage others to also do so, even though I understand that sometimes people feel under pressure to publish).

Comment: There would seem to be some truth to this around the surreals:
"...at least for now, I'm finished. All the questions that have yet to be answered are too hard." -- Jacob Lurie on surreal numbers, 1996  (https://www.nytimes.com/1996/04/07/magazine/sunday-april-7-1996-a-question-for-jacob-lurie.html)

Comment: The correct remark is "They're allowed to stop working when things get too complicated", and I don't see how this is substantially different from any other field of study.  Any real-life scientific work involves taking a small piece of a big picture, and either controlling parameters or making simplifying assumptions.  People in other academic subjects also publish partial results, perhaps after they roughly calculate the expected marginal utility of further effort.

Comment: I think the main mentality of 90% mathematicians is publish or perish. haha

Comment: I definitely do NOT think it's true that "mathematicians stop working when things get too difficult"

Comment: In terms of generality, this question is not far to "how do mathematicians write papers?", which is a little broad.

Comment: Since I've heard Chomsky speak on this theme before, I think the real point he's leading up to is that despite its conceptual power, mathematics isn't, and can't be, used to solve scientific problems the way a Laplacean demon could. We can't understand in detail what is going on in a cup of coffee, much less "how a dog works", etc. etc.